# Deploy Java EE Project in Weblogic

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, weblogic, eclipse-wtp

I have WebLogic installed in my computer. I already added it as a server in my Eclipse IDE. How do I configure my Web application to run or for it to be deployed on the WebLogic server. I found a sample project and found a `weblogic.xml` in it. Where do I start? Do I need to add something, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your web application is already a "*Dynamic Web Application*", then you should be able to deploy it just by right clicking on it, then *Run As* > *Run on Server* and choose the WebLogic Server runtime.

If this doesn't work, maybe you need to add the right facet to your project. Right click on your project and go to *Properties* > *Project Facets* and check that *Dynamic Web Module* is checked.

If this still doesn't work, maybe recreate a "*Dynamic Web Application*" from scratch and move (or copy) your sources to this newly created project.

Many tutorials are actually available at the [WTP Community Resources](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/community/communityresources.php) page. See for example [Using the Eclipse Web Tools Platform with Apache Tomcat](http://www.windofkeltia.com/j2ee/wtp-tutorial.html). It is not specific to WebLogic but if you already have it setup in Eclipse, it should be easy to adapt the specific parts.

PS: It's hard to say anything about your sample project and the `weblogic.xml` as you didn't provide any detail about them. Maybe try to follow the advices above and, if you still have problems, update your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of resources on using Eclipse with WebLogic, including Oracl'es Enterprise Pack for Eclipse.  It's hard to tell without more information, but you need a WebLogic Domain configured with at least an Admin Server to deploy the web application to.  When doing local development, it's acceptable to deploy applications to the Admin Server, but beyond this you typically want an Admin Server and a managed server where the application will get deployed to.

Here's some info on Eclipse and WebLogic - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/eclipse/learnmore/index.html

Comment: Direct unambiguous link: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javaee/marx-oepe-spring-095718.html

Answer (score -1):

Question is missing much details. You can find some detailed help here

http://download-llnw.oracle.com/docs/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/deployment/index.html